# How to Create a Quiz in Excel

Tags: excel

I need to create a quiz. It should consists of questions and possible cases for the answers. After passing the test the score must be computed and displayed. I think, it is possible to do in Excel. Or, maybe be a special good software exists for this purpose. I would be grateful for any tutorial or references materials on this topic.

Comment: There exists software like http://www.wondershare.com/pro/quizcreator.html, which makes your question off-topic for SO.

Comment: well, you can always learn VBA and use it...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps u have seen flash embedded in excel. You can easily make quiz GUI in flash.
And you can easily embedd this into a excel sheet.